# If I try a new email client like K9-mail, can I go back to my original email just by uninstalling it?

Tags: email, k9-mail

Before I try something I cannot easily reverse ( *and to confirm something I think I already know the answer for* ): if I install **another email client** ( like K9-mail ) on my *Samsung phone* of even more on my *Archos 101 tablet*, **can I revert back to the email client I already have just be uninstalling** the new email client ?

Will I get a choice of email clients ( like you have now when you install Opera or Firefox ) ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you first install an application that can handle the same intent as another application install (for the sake of this example, let's say a home launcher, but this works for any similar apps), then the first time you'd press the home button (which calls an intent to go to the home screen, which you now have 2 apps that could handle it), you'll get a selection screen of applications that can fulfill that intent and you'll have the option to set one of them as default.

If set an application as default and you no longer wish to use that application as default you can either uninstall the application OR you can go to Settings --> applications --> manage apps --> go to the app in particular --> and click on "clear defaults".  This will reset the default application for that intent, so the next time you'd press the home button you would again get a selection of home launchers to choose from.

Comment: To clarify somewhat here: you do not even need to remove K9 mail to go back to the stock mail application and ... yes, you will see a choice of email clients.

Comment: Second clarification: Whenever installing/uninstalling/updating an app which handles an intent also handled by another installed app, the "default" is reset (i.e. the popup to chose which app to use will re-appear then). So no worries :)

Answer (score 6):

Short answer Yes.

It should act exactly like having a second browser... until you set it as your default Android should prompt you to pick what client you want to use.  If you choose K9 as your default and then delete it Android will be smart enough to revert back to the default client.

Comment: Can you please explain the down-vote?