# If you install another home locker program which one does Android chooses when it locks your phone?

Tags: lock-screens

I asked a similar question regarding an alternate email program here [My similar question about an email client](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7444/if-i-try-a-new-email-client-like-k9-mail-can-i-go-back-to-my-original-email-just), and got a logical answer. Thanks.

However, what happens, I now wonder, when you **install another home locker program**( *I presume this is the name for the software that locks your screen , no* ) ?

Since the device itself 'locks' your phone, you may not be around to choose the one you want to use.

Or does , installing another one, automatically disables the current ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically, the replacement lockscreen program will have a service running that recognizes when the phone 'locks' and then overrides the default lockscreen with the one you've created through that app.  There is typically a delay of a few seconds, so it's possible to still see the default lockscreen on occasion.  I've been using `WidgetLocker` for some time now and have been very happy with it.  It's available on the Market.